How to activate a Trello export CSV URL in C#
Our trello boards allow exporting CSV files. The link format is simple:
https://trello.com/b/abcdefg.csv?cards=visible
All I have to do is replace abcdefg with the 8-character board code. When I paste that completed link in Chrome or whatever browser, it will automatically download the CSV to my Downloads directory.
I have 8 boards I want to download daily and then process. How can I use C# to "activate" said links programmatically?
